# Does there exist an uncountable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, s.t for every $a \in A$ & every $\epsilon>0$, $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\not\subset A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Does there exist an uncountable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, such that for every $a \in A$ and every $\epsilon>0$, $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\not\subset A$?

I am not sure what the answer is, but I am having trouble trying to construct such a set. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: The set of rational numbers is dense and countable.

Comment: Ah, thanks. R\Q. Duh

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) totally disconnected set is also an example.